# How to use local REST API on smartphone?

Tags: android, rest, networking, dns, local

The environment: There is a REST API written in PHP running on a computer in my local network. I want a smartphone app to use this REST API just as it was on a real server.

The problem: How can I do that? Anyway I have to establish a URL, reachable by my smartphone, pointing to my computer. It doesn't matter for me, if the URL is a "real registrated url" or a local url such as "example.dev".

The restrictions: I don't want to have my smartphone rooted and I have no static IP.

Does anyone have some advices for me? It would be really great to come over this.

My thoughts: I was thinking about a local dns server (e.g. on a raspberry pi). But I don't know if this works, because all the guides say, you already must have two domains registrated and already pointing to static IP adresses to the target system.

Thank you for your help and I hope, nobody else has already asked that.

Luke

UPDATE: I don't want to run it on a real server, because it's currently under development. Forgot to mention that. So I want to develop the whole system locally.

Comment: If it is your local network and you have admin rights on your router - try to bind IP address to your computer (which hosts your REST API) MAC address - this way every single time this computer connects to the network - it will receive the same IP address so you can use it in your Android app. The other way is to configure DynDNS if it is applicable for your case.

Comment: There is still the problem when I have more than one applications running on the same computer which should be available through the network